# Is there a way to display vimeo videos on my website from embedded url in database?

Tags: php, mysql, video, embed, vimeo

I am trying to create where people can input a video url and it will save into my database. The thing is that after I've saved the video url in my database, how can I show it on the page using PHP?

For example, using this embedded vimeo video, how can I display it after I've called it from my database.

**If I want to show it from the database like this:**

```
$result = mysqli_query($connect,"SELECT * FROM web where video <> '' && video IS NOT NULL");

    if ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result))
    {
```

**How can I display this?**

```
<iframe src="https://player.vimeo.com/video/90312869" width="500" height="281" 
        frameborder="0" webkitallowfullscreen mozallowfullscreen allowfullscreen>
            </iframe>
            <p><a href="https://vimeo.com/90312869">360&deg; 
        Video using 6 GoPro Cameras - spherical panorama timelapse</a> 
        from <a href="https://vimeo.com/j0n4s">j0n4s</a> on <a href="https://vimeo.com">Vimeo</a>.</p>
```

Comment: You can display only the data you have, if you have only the url than that is the only thing you can display, you cannot display the title, author etc if you don't have that information unless you save each of this data.

Comment: @Ales I know I can display the embedded url, but is there a way to show it as a video on my page?

Comment: Just output the the iframe with the url of the video from database

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Like this:

```
$result = mysqli_query($connect,"SELECT * FROM web where video <> '' && video IS NOT NULL");

if ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result))
{
   $url = $row['url'];
} 

<iframe src="<?php echo $url; ?>" width="500" height="281" 
    frameborder="0" webkitallowfullscreen mozallowfullscreen allowfullscreen></iframe>

        <p><a href="<?php echo $url; ?>">360&deg; 
    Video using 6 GoPro Cameras - spherical panorama timelapse</a> 
    from <a href="https://vimeo.com/j0n4s">j0n4s</a> on <a href="https://vimeo.com">Vimeo</a>.</p>
```

Answer (score 0):

in html 5 I would write it like this

```
<?php
 // get the url 
 $sourceURL = value of the extracted column from your table which is a url;
 //Extract the file name
 $fileName = new SplFileInfo::getFilename ( $sourceURL );

 // Get the file extention
 $fileExtention = new SplFileInfo::getExtension ( $fileName );

 $sourceHTML = '<source src='.$sourceURL.' type="video/'.$fileExtention.'">';


?>

<video width="400" controls>
  <?php echo $sourceHTML;  ?>
  Your browser does not support HTML5 video.
</video>
```